# HOw to give static ip to router from window XP LAN

Tags: windows-xp, router, windows-vista, static-ip

I have the USB modem internet connection.
I am using ICS sharing in XP to share my internet connection.

ON window XP LAN i have set up the LAN IP as

```
192.168.137.1
255.255.255.0
```

Now i have joined the cable from that XP LAN to another LAPTOP running vista

Now if set the LAN on VISTA to get ip automatically them internet don't work
but if manually set the ip to

```
192.168.137.3
255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.137.1
```

Then my internet works

But i want to join that LAN cable from XP to rouer so that i can use router to divide internet.

But i don't know how i can give static ipto router because i think somehow

that LAN on XP is not giving the IP address

Answer (score 1):

Normally, ICS will configure the enabled LAN adapter automatically. You should not need to manually assign any IP configuration to the LAN adapter which has ICS enabled. It will also setup the DHCP server on that LAN adapter.

Perhaps by manually assigning the IP configuration on that adapter (if you did), you somehow disabled the DHCP server that would normally be set up automatically.

Comment: should i setup ics on usb connection which has internet ot Lan adapter--from where i connect to other comp

Comment: Connection/adapter (may not work with certain connections/adapters - e.g. pseudo adapters/devices) with the Internet connection that you want to share, the other adapters will be configured by Windows automatically in response.

Comment: XP does not have a DHCP server that will run for ICS, a third party DHCP server may need to be added, or ZeroConfig enabled(does not route though)

Comment: Actually, all versions of ICS includes basic DHCP server functionality (basically fixed to the 192.168.1.0/24 net, if my memory serves me correctly) - no separate DHCP server needed when running an ICS network.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the DHCP server on the router to assign the IPs to other hosts on its LAN, and connect its WAN port to the XP pc.  On the router you would need to set it as a Static IP (similar to the setting you needed to place on the VISTA machine)